# Showing bad request while fetching data using graphQl?

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql

The getProductById is in another js file. When I am trying to use this by putting some static id in gql playground, it is working,

```
export const getProductById = gql`
      query getProductById($id: String!) {
        product(id: $id) {
          id
          brand
          name
          gallery
          inStock
          prices {
            currency
            amount
          }
          category
          description
          attributes {
            id
            name
            type
            items {
              displayValue
              value
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
    
    
    const{data, loading, error} = useQuery(getProductById,{
        variables:{id}
      })
```

When I am consoling log data it is showing undefined.
It is also returning error which is
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Comment: Are you really sure, the JS variable `id` is correctly set in your app? Just to make sure, your query works as in the graphql explorer, you could try setting a hardcoded value `const{data, loading, error} = useQuery(getProductById,{
        variables:{id: "my-id"}
      })
    ` If your `id` variable is set correctly, could you post the payload of your request that is sent to your server (from the network tab)?

Comment: I have checked the variable ID, and it is correct. Moreover, I tried setting hard-coded value, which also showed the same error.  **Below is the payload request**

Comment: **{operationName: "getProductById", variables: {id: "jacket-canada-goosee"},…}
operationName: "getProductById"
query: "query getProductById($id: String!) {\n  product(id: $id) {\n    id\n    brand\n    name\n    gallery\n    inStock\n    prices {\n      currency\n      amount\n      __typename\n    }\n    category\n    description\n    attributes {\n      id\n      name\n      type\n      items {\n        displayValue\n        value\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}"
variables: {id: "jacket-canada-goosee"}**

Comment: Following is the API endpoint for your reference [link](https://github.com/scandiweb/junior-react-endpoint). I am using the **product** query

Comment: The payload doesn't look correct. The json object at the beginning doesn't contain the query and also why are all fields after the first json object duplicated? Is it a copy+paste mistake?

Comment: I was writing the wrong query. `export const GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID = gql
  query getProductById($productId: String!) {
    product(id: $productId) {
      id
      brand
      name
      gallery
      inStock
      prices {
        currency {
          label
          symbol
        }
        amount
      }
      category
      description
      attributes {
        id
        name
        type
        items {
          displayValue
          value
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
;`

Comment: Earlier I was writing using the same variable i.e., 'id' while sending the query. That's why JSON objects are duplicated.